# Query Date reference issue

Tags: excel

I have a connection to an SQL Database and it pulls in data into a table. On another sheet I have a formula that VLOOKUPs a 'Date' column within this table. It finds the date and displays what I want. Then, I have a formula within the same sheet that uses said date to run a calculation.

This is where the issue arises. It simply does not calculate correctly BUT if I manually type the date shown over the formula, it performs the calculation accordingly. So formula is right, connection is right, but somehow I cannot reference said cell.

Do you have a solution for said problem?

Example:

**Sheet 1**
*SQL Table*
Column B (Date)

**Sheet 2**
*Formulas*
Cell A1 = VLOOKUP(Date)
Cell A2 = A1+30

Comment: Probably the date is a string and not a date.  But when you type in a date you actually get a date.  Try setting A2 to =INT(A1)+30

Comment: geniuses both of ya! thank you! I just added DATEVALUE to the VLOOKUP and it works like a charm, so yes, it was bringing it in as a text! BRAVO!